# Multiple users collaborating on Twine project

Tags: collaboration, twine-game-engine

Is there any (smooth) possibility for multiple users to collaborate on a Twine project?

I've just been introduced to [twinery.org](http://twinery.org), and thinking about the possibilities of using it to teach programming in basic school. My colleagues and I thought it would be an interesting project for pupils to collaborate on a story, making perhaps one passage each.

Can we do this in a smoother way than asking them to send their code to a teacher who adds it together and publishes?

Anyone with experience of this, or thoughts of how I can go about?

Answer (score 0):

2 users will never be able to work on the same story cause of the pid field inside the HTML file. users would need to alternate before grabbing the latest changes. I withdraw my answer.